# Golang print Array Values in html template

Tags: html, http, templates, go

I dont know how to print values out of an array into a html template
This is my struct

```
type Lampen struct {
Values [10]string
}
```

and my code for prasing the template is the following

```
title := "moodlights"
p := &lampen.Lampen{}
err := p.LoadLampValues(title)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error loading Config File")
    for i := range p.Values {
        p.Values[i] = "0"

    }
}
t, _ := template.ParseFiles("template.html")
t.Execute(w, p)
```

What it does is, that it loads the Values from a JSON File.
But now I dont know how to print the Values into the html file. 
What works is the following:

```
<div>Lampe0: <input type="text" name="Lampe0" value={{index .Values 0}} maxlength="6"></div>
```

But of course it does not escape the Values in the html so XSS is a problem.

Update: For Cross site Scripting the Problem I want to show here is:
If the json file contains the following

```
    "Values": [
    "\u003e",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
]
```

which is the equivalent to >, the html printed will be

```
<div>Lampe0: <input type="text" name="Lampe0" value=> maxlength="6"></div>
```

So its not escaped

How to printf it into the html so its escaped?

Update2:
The old working Version with escaping can be seen at https://github.com/Binary-Kitchen/gokitchenmood

Comment: are you using html/template? http://play.golang.org/p/sXuVXjGsCR

Comment: yeah Im using html/template. As said the problem is if you now put in somthing like > < " its not escaped

Comment: please make an example to show what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I was using text/template and not html/template. So it was basically and fault on my side. Thanks to JimB to point it out though.